# extracting combined string from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, get, set

I am scanning three different inputs and converting them into a single string using `toString`.  Then I want to edit the individual inputs.
For example:

```
name phoneNumber address 
sarmad 12345 myhouse
```

How can I edit 'myhouse'?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
        CreateFormat FormatObject = new CreateFormat();

        int choice;
        String phoneNumber;
        String name,address;
        String format = "Empty";
        int x = 1;
        int flag = 0;

        do{
            try{
                System.out.println("Enter your choice");
                System.out.printf("1:Enter new data\n2:Display data");
                choice = Integer.parseInt(input.next());

                switch (choice){

                    case 1:{
                        System.out.println("Enter name  ");
                        name = input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter phone number");
                        phoneNumber = input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter address");
                        address = input.next();
                        format = FormatObject.toString(phoneNumber, name, address);
                        arraylist.add(format);
                        flag++;
                    }
                        break;

                    case 2:{
                        System.out.println("Name   Phone number   Address");
                        System.out.println();

                        for(int i = 0; i < flag; i++){
                            System.out.println(arraylist.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                        break;

                    default:{
                        System.out.println("Enter right choice");
                    }
                }
            }

            catch(Exception InputMismatchException){
                System.out.println("Enter right choice");   
            }
        } while(x == 1);
    }
}
```

my `toString` method:

```
public class CreateFormat {
    String phoneNumber;
    String nameUser;
    String addressUser;

    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s  %s  %s", nameUser,phoneNumber,addressUser);
    }

    public String toString (String phone,String name,String address){
        phoneNumber = phone;
        nameUser = name;
        addressUser = address;
        return String.format("%s  %s  %s", nameUser,phoneNumber,addressUser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is to implement [setters/getters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) for your properties.

```
public class CreateFormat {
 private String phoneNumber;
 private String nameUser;
 private String addressUser;

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
   this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
   return phoneNumber;
}
// Similar set & get methods for other properties too.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i allowed myself to make some changes to your code, because my understanding is, that it would be easier and smother to give up String and use the Object itself instead.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<CreateFormat> arrayList = new ArrayList<CreateFormat>();

        int choice;
        String phoneNumber;
        String name; //sepperated for readability
        String address;
        //String format="Empty"; not used anymore
        int x = 1;
        //int flag = 0; is not necessary
        do{
            try{   
                System.out.println("Enter your choice");
                System.out.printf("1:Enter new data\n2:Display data");
                choice = input.nextInt();//Integer.parseInt(input.next());
                switch (choice){
                    case 1:{
                        System.out.println("Enter name  ");
                        name = input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter phone number");
                        phoneNumber = input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter address");
                        address = input.next();
                        arraylist.add(new CreateFormat(name, phoneNumber, address)); //changed to an object of type CreateFormat instead of String
                        //flag++; not necessary
                    }
                        break;

                    case 2:{
                        //System.out.println("Name   Phone number   Address");
                        //System.out.println();
                        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){// size = method from the ArrayList library
                            System.out.println("Name:" + arrayList.get(i).getNameUser());
                            System.out.println("Phone Number:" + arrayList.get(i).getPhoneNumber());
                            System.out.println("Address:" + arrayList.get(i).getAddressUser());
                            //System.out.println(arraylist.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                    default:{
                        System.out.println("Enter right choice");
                    }
                }
            }

            catch(Exception InputMismatchException){
            System.out.println("Enter right choice");   
            }
        }while(x==1);
    }
}
```

Create Format:

```
public class CreateFormat {

    String phoneNumber;
    String nameUser;
    String addressUser;

    public CreateFormat(String phoneNumber, String nameUser, String addressUser){
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.nameUser = nameUser;
        this.addressUser = addressUser;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getNameUser(){
        return this.nameUser;
    }

    public String getAddressUser(){
        return this.addressUser;
    }
}
```

I couldn't test it yet, so feel free to ask if there are some issues.